# How to make automatic Table creator in SQLite

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

Is there any option how to make in Android SQL Lite something like automatic table creator? My problem is that i would like to store multiple tables with different names (chosen by user) and with different collumns (Demands on users set up parametres). Then be able to find all these tables and work with them. Is this possible or i shloud use different type of saving these data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use foreign keys? Create one table with the "table names" and use the _id as foreign key in other tables.